# order by custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I have custom field (date) in my wordpress site, that contain a value like this `june 16,2013`.
How can i treat this field this as date and sort?. 
Is there any way to sort posts by custon_field date?

I tried in my php page with this code,

```
$args = array(
 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_key' =>'release_date'
);
query_posts($args);
```

it's getting data in sort order, but not based on date, the field is considered as string not date, how can I treated this as date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$args = array(
 'orderby' => "DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%M %d,%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')", 
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_key' =>'release_date'
);
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: @Nisam If this answer helped you in solving your issue the you may up vote the answer as an appreciation

Answer (score 0):

You can set all dates you want to sort in an array and convert them using strtotime(), then simply use sort(). There **might** be a more efficient way.

Comment: how can i rewrite the query for that one ?

Comment: what query? You have provided no code as well as you have tagged this as php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link_banner', true); 
$date_convert = strtotime($date);
$args = array(
 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'meta_key' =>$date_convert 
);
query_posts($args);
```